# Cálculo incorrecto de los días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños cuando se ingresa la fecha de cumpleaños actual

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un formulario HTML con un campo de entrada de tipo date donde los usuarios pueden ingresar su fecha de cumpleaños. Estoy utilizando JavaScript para calcular los días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños a partir de la fecha actual.

El problema que encuentro es que cuando ingreso la fecha de cumpleaños que coincide exactamente con la fecha actual (por ejemplo, 15 de mayo de 2023), el cálculo muestra "Faltan 366 días para tu próximo cumpleaños". Esto parece ser incorrecto, ya que en realidad es el día de mi cumpleaños.

Aquí está el fragmento de código que estoy utilizando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cálculo de días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños</title>
  <script>
    function calcularDiasRestantes() {
      // Obtén la fecha actual
      var fechaActual = new Date();

      // Obtén el valor del campo de entrada de fecha de cumpleaños
      var fechaCumpleanos = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaCumpleanos').value);

      // Establece la fecha del cumpleaños del usuario al año actual
      fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear());

      // Compara las fechas para determinar si es el cumpleaños o calcular los días restantes
      if (fechaCumpleanos > fechaActual) {
        // Calcula la diferencia en milisegundos entre las fechas
        var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();

        // Convierte la diferencia de tiempo a días
        var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
      } else if (
        fechaCumpleanos.getDate() === fechaActual.getDate() &&
        fechaCumpleanos.getMonth() === fechaActual.getMonth()
      ) {
        document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "¡Feliz cumpleaños!";
      } else {
        // Si la fecha de cumpleaños ya pasó en el año actual, calcula los días restantes para el próximo año
        fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear() + 1);

        var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();
        var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Cálculo de días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños</h1>
  <label for="fechaCumpleanos">Ingresa tu fecha de cumpleaños:</label>
  <input type="date" id="fechaCumpleanos">
  <button onclick="calcularDiasRestantes()">Calcular</button>
  <p id="resultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bueno, no veo que estás capturando nunca al valor del input `fechaCumpleanos` para hacer el cálculo... también la función `calcularDiasRestantes()` no existe... en pocas palabras, tu HTML no tiene ninguna utilidad... ¿Estás seguro que el código está completo?...

Comment: Claro, muchas gracias no habia caido en cuenta

Comment: @Cris223511.dev voy a editar la pregunta para que veas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece ser un problema de zonas horarias.

Ocurría que si ponemos un día antes de la fecha actual, decía que faltaba 365 días, si ponemos el mismo día, faltaban 366 días, y el día siguiente, faltaban 1 día.

```js
function calcularDiasRestantes() {
  // Obtén la fecha actual
  var fechaActual = new Date();

  // Obtén el valor del campo de entrada de fecha de cumpleaños
  var fechaCumpleanos = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaCumpleanos').value);

  // Establece la fecha del cumpleaños del usuario al año actual
  fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear());

  // Compara las fechas para determinar si es el cumpleaños o calcular los días restantes
  if (fechaCumpleanos > fechaActual) {
    // Calcula la diferencia en milisegundos entre las fechas
    var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();

    // Convierte la diferencia de tiempo a días
    var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
  } else if (
    fechaCumpleanos.getDate() === fechaActual.getDate() &&
    fechaCumpleanos.getMonth() === fechaActual.getMonth()
  ) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "¡Feliz cumpleaños!";
  } else {
    // Si la fecha de cumpleaños ya pasó en el año actual, calcula los días restantes para el próximo año
    fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear() + 1);

    var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();
    var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Cálculo de días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños</h1>
<label for="fechaCumpleanos">Ingresa tu fecha de cumpleaños:</label>
<input type="date" id="fechaCumpleanos">
<button onclick="calcularDiasRestantes()">Calcular</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Podemos solucionarlo agregando la siguiente línea de código para que las horas en `UTC` estén en `0` y así hacer una comparación precisa y no ocurran estos errores, es decir, con esto aseguramos que las fechas sean exactas y no sean afectadas **por la diferencia de horas entre zonas horarias**.

```
var fechaActual = new Date();
fechaActual.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function calcularDiasRestantes() {
  // Obtén la fecha actual
  var fechaActual = new Date();
  fechaActual.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // Obtén el valor del campo de entrada de fecha de cumpleaños
  var fechaCumpleanos = new Date(document.getElementById('fechaCumpleanos').value);

  // Establece la fecha del cumpleaños del usuario al año actual
  fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear());

  // Compara las fechas para determinar si es el cumpleaños o calcular los días restantes
  if (fechaCumpleanos > fechaActual) {
    // Calcula la diferencia en milisegundos entre las fechas
    var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();

    // Convierte la diferencia de tiempo a días
    var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
  } else if (
    fechaCumpleanos.getDate() === fechaActual.getDate() &&
    fechaCumpleanos.getMonth() === fechaActual.getMonth()
  ) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "¡Feliz cumpleaños!";
  } else {
    // Si la fecha de cumpleaños ya pasó en el año actual, calcula los días restantes para el próximo año
    fechaCumpleanos.setFullYear(fechaActual.getFullYear() + 1);

    var diferenciaTiempo = fechaCumpleanos.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime();
    var diasRestantes = Math.ceil(diferenciaTiempo / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    document.getElementById('resultado').textContent = "Faltan " + diasRestantes + " días para tu próximo cumpleaños.";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Cálculo de días restantes para el próximo cumpleaños</h1>
<label for="fechaCumpleanos">Ingresa tu fecha de cumpleaños:</label>
<input type="date" id="fechaCumpleanos">
<button onclick="calcularDiasRestantes()">Calcular</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono

Comment: Sólo un apunte: estando en 2023, con [IE ya descontinuado hace tiempo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer). ¿Porqué seguir usando `var` en vez de [`let`](https://caniuse.com/?search=let) y [`const`](https://caniuse.com/?search=const)?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Dada una fecha de cumpleaños, se desea calcular la cantidad de días que faltan para el siguiente cumpleaños desde la fecha actual.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Esto se puede hacer mediante simples matemáticas. Podemos calcular la cantidad de días transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero del año en curso hasta la fecha de cumpleaños, y podemos calcular la cantidad de días desde el 01 de Enero del año en curso hasta la fecha actual del sistema.

Al comparar ambos valores se tienen 2 posibilidades:

- Si la cantidad de días transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero hasta el cumpleaños es mayor o igual a la cantidad de días transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero hasta la fecha actual, significa que los días para que se cumplan años será la diferencia entre ambas.
- En caso contrario, significa que el cumpleaños ya ha pasado en este año por lo cual simplemente debemos restar 365 menos la cantidad de días transcurridos desde el 01 de Enero hasta la fecha actual y sumarle luego la cantidad de días transcurridos hasta la fecha de cumpleaños más 1.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const ONE_DAY_MILLIS = 1000 * 3600 * 24;

function calcularDiasTranscurridos(fecha) {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const unoEnero = new Date(year,0,1,0,0,0,0);
  return Math.floor((new Date(
    year, fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate(),
    0, 0, 0, 0,).valueOf()
    - unoEnero.valueOf())
    / ONE_DAY_MILLIS);
}

document
  .getElementById('calcular')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
    const fechaCumple = document.getElementById('cumple').value;
    if(!fechaCumple) {
      return;
    }
    const diasTranscurridosCumple = calcularDiasTranscurridos(new Date(fechaCumple));
    const diasTranscurridosHoy = calcularDiasTranscurridos(new Date());
    const diferencia = diasTranscurridosCumple - diasTranscurridosHoy;
    let resultado;
    if(diferencia >= 0) {
      resultado = diferencia
        ? `Faltan ${diferencia} día${diferencia === 1 ? '' : 's'} para su cumpleaños`
        : 'Feliz cumpleaños';
    } else {
      const dias = diasTranscurridosCumple + 365 - diasTranscurridosHoy + 1;
      resultado = `Faltan ${dias} días`
    }
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerText = resultado;
  });
```

```html
<label for="cumple">Ingresa la fecha de cumpleaños: </label>
<input type="date" name="cumple" id="cumple">
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
<br>
<span id="resultado"></span>
```

De esta forma se calculan los días que faltan para el próximo cumpleaños.